# Table and table content should resize in HTML according to device screen

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new to HTML and designing a page that picks up files from a directory. Another column contains checkbox for selecting the files. When I open the page from my mobile browser, the table size does not change, hence i need to maximize the table manually. Is there any way in HTML that I can render the table according to the browser sizes? I tried googling for the same but in vain. It will be great if someone just redirects me to the concept.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your relevant code, what you have tried, and the results you have gotten. It makes it difficult to determine what is wrong without those things.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman: I had tried adding the screenshot, but as I am new to stackoverflow, the system wont allow me to do so.The code is very basic level like following: <tr>
    <td width="33" align="center">*</td>
    <td width="382">File Name</td>
  </tr>  I shall try media queries as pointed by other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **responsive web design**.There are few possible ways to do it. You can select according to your need

> 1. You can use media queries in which you define different stylesheets for different screens. This is the most used way currently. 
>    Sneak Peek:
>      http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ and
>      https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
> 2. You can use the viewport meta tag. 
>    Sneak Peek:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
> 3. You can design everything in % (fluid responsive) but that part is very tricky. From my experience I can say that designing a full
>      website giving everything in % is very difficult.

I will suggest you to learn media query. Its quite simple and reliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This is exactly the type of answer I had requested. I shall check the media queries functionality. :)

Comment: @user3403410 vote up and check the answer if it's able to solve your question

Comment: had checked it at first instance. cant vote up as it requires 15 reps

Answer (score 1):

Please add the code...there's no definite answer if we can't see what you have right now.  You can add

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to your head tags for starters.

In your CSS file:

```
/* Retina display */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 980px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Mobile HD */
@media screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 760px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}

/* Mobile LD */
@media screen and (max-width: 350px){
    .responsive-table{
        [CSS CODE];
    }
}
```